# SELECT after CREATE TABLE AS takes a long time to run

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I needed to create a temp table and then used that temp table in a select query. When I put these statements in a function, it'll take a long time to run the second statement. Like this:

```
BEGIN 
   CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT….
   INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM tableA join temp…
END;
```

I realized that when I run them individually with about 60 seconds between the runs, the second statement take about 2 seconds to run. If I waited 45 seconds it will take a long time to run. For example, if I execute the following statements one by one (not in a function):

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT….

SELECT pg_sleep(60);

INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM tableA join temp…
```

It'll take a short time to execute the INSERT one. But when I highlighted them and run them all together, it took forever to execute again.

I tried to put them in a function within different BEGIN/END blocks. Like this

```
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT….
   SELECT pg_sleep(120);
END;

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM tableA join temp…
END;
```

Still didn't work.

Why the wait in between? Why they didn't work when put in a function? Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect the issue is with plan selection due to the table not having stats yet. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT….
ANALYZE;
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM tableA join temp…
```

P.s. +1 for using real ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

This is not  direct answer to the question, but if the problem is that you feel that you need a temporary table like that, which is rarely necessary, then I would instead try one of the following three alternatives in this order:

1. Use a subquery instead of a temporary table. The optimiser is very good at handling complex SQL.
2. Use a common table expression (WITH clause): If the result set is very large then the data will be materialised to a temporary segment, and if it is not then it can be treated as a subquery.
3. Use a global temporary table. You won't have to use execute immediate, and can index the table or gather statistics on it (rarely required, due to optimiser dynamic sampling).

To diagnose your actual issue I would look into monitoring the session through tracing, or using AWR.

Comment: I did use sub-query. For some reason, the sub-query also took an extremely long time to run. It was much much faster with the temp table. I also used CREATE TABLE temp DROP ON COMMIT and that didn't work as well.

Comment: Well that syntax is completely invalid. "create global temporary table (col1, col2 ...) on commit delete rows". I think you would have done better to try and diagnose the cause of the slow running sub-query, possibly rewriting it as a common table expression, before moving to temp tables.